# Pass parallel and forkCount paramters to testng through maven command line

Tags: maven, testng

How can you pass "parallel" and "forkCount" properties to testNG using the maven command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html):

1. [parallel](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#parallel)

> (TestNG provider) When you use the `parallel` attribute, TestNG will try to run all your test methods in separate threads, except for methods that depend on each other, which will be run in the same thread in order to respect their order of execution.
>
> **User property is**: `parallel`.

2. [forkCount](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount)

> **User property is**: `forkCount`.

So you can use them like:

`mvn test -Dparallel=<value> -DforkCount=<value>`